# PHP5 HTTPRequest2 (PEAR) fails when $url parameter contains :port

Tags: php, httprequest, pear

I have a problem with HTTP_Request2 object: when I make a request to a server that doesn't serve on the default (80) TCP port, HTTPRequest2 library launches the following exception:

```
"Unable to connect to tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080"
```

I've tried to google for HTTPRequest2 library usage, but so far I haven't found any "non-80 port" scenario.

P.S. The same server, when configured properly, works well on port 80 with this PEAR library.

Comment: I take it you are sure port 8080 is open on the target?

Comment: yeah.. sure, I've tested it several times. One server can connect to another from other HTTP "clients".